# A static member variable export

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

static error:

```
   in test1.dll:
    xxx.h
    class AFX_EXT_CLASS CTest1
    {
        static int num;
    }

    xxx.cpp
    int CTest1::num = 0;

    in a cpp of test2.dll: test2 is dependent test1.dll
    ...
    int i = CTest1::num;
    ...

    in a cpp of App: App is dependent test1.dll & test2.dll
    ...
    int i = CTest1::num;
    ...
```

in test2.dll, "Unresolved external symbol" on static: CTest1::num.
but in App, no problem.

BTW:if i use other function of CTest1, no problem.

Help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Why don't you use `extern` keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is stripping the symbol. You can try `__declspecimport`. You can also try `extern`ing the variable and creating an artificial reference in another project.